# How do I check if a line is behind a vertex?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, raytracing

I have an algorithm where I trace convex polygons from a light source, all contained between 4 walls.This is the algorithm:

Preparation - add all vertices to an array, sorted by their angle from the light source and then add all lines made by all vertices in another array.

Loop all vertices and rotate the ray to their angles
  Set each vertex to be the nearest point.
  For each vertex loop all lines and intersect the ray with them, if a line/ray intersection point is closer than the previous nearest point then set this as the nearest point.

This works perfectly except for this case:
[image]
The green lines aren't being considered by the algorithm.How can I make it continue beyond the ends of the polygon?

Comment: Why not check if your calculated intersection point is also a vertex (within some small radius of error)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, can you explain please

Comment: Could you explain that why the green lines aren't being considered by the algorithm? In my view, they are considered since the polygon is somehow transparent.

Comment: I'd prefer to see some context. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What should be the expected result of the algorithm? The closest vertex/nearest point?

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason why the green lines should be considered! The ray falls on the vertex, which is still part of the solid polygon. It is therefore logical that the ray will not continue further (along the green line). Your algorithm is correct and consistent!

Comment: yes the only thing I can think of is that the finite number of rays on ray-trace (not back-ray-trace) projects all objects smaller then they are because of this. Of course if it will pass through edges then they would appear most likely larger ...

Comment: @Spektre, I think it's the contrary of what you describe - the ray would *not* pass through the *vertices* (not edges) as opposed to what OP expected.